# Android timer fires only once

Tags: android, timer

I have this code where I want to try to send an e-mail report every hour (in the example to every second). If there is no coverage, try again within an hour etc. Somehow I managed to break the timer in sendUnsendedReports(): it fires only once. If I remove the call to sendUnsendedReports() than the timer is working perfectly. Even with the try-catch block around it, the timer only fires once. Please advice.

```
private void createAndScheduleSendReport() {
        delayedSendTimer = new Timer();
        delayedSendTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.w("UrenRegistratie", "Try to send e-mail...");
                try{
                  sendUnsendedReports();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    // added try catch block to be sure of uninterupted execution
                }
                Log.w("UrenRegistratie", "Mail scheduler goes to sleep.");
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: ... so what are you doing in sendunsendedreports()? Seems to be that'd be where you should be looking.

Comment: ...and at the very least you should log any exceptions you (might) encounter.

Comment: Shouldn't it be impossible to break the Timer? In the sendUnsendedReports() I am turning off flight mode, sleeping for a few sec, producing some xml report and try to send it using gmail and turn flight mode on again.

Comment: FYI: It's Unsent.  Unsended isn't a word.  I wouldn't usually point it out if it was in your comments, but it's part of your code so it should be refactored, IMO

Comment: @DavidM I only added the try/catch block for testing. The method shouldn't throw anything. And it doesn't otherwise the try/catch block made a difference

Comment: The variant of `schedule` you are using is supposed to add delay of 1000 milliseconds between each execution. That means between every execution it will take 1 sec. So for instance your method `sendUnsendedReports()` is taking 5 min to execute then when you schedule timer for first time, next execution will take place after 5 min and 1 sec. That's is exactly what is happening to you. If you remove call to this method then it virtually take 0 sec to execute `TimerTask` and you end up seeing calls every second.

Comment: You can use `scheduleAtFixedRate()` but in this case I won't recommend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that sometimes timer doesn't works well as it should be. The alternative of this is use of `Handler` instead `TimerTask`.

You can use it like :

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      try{
              sendUnsendedReports();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                // added try catch block to be sure of uninterupted execution
            }
      /* and here comes the "trick" */
      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
};
```

Check out [this link](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/) for more detail. :)

Comment: This isn't an answer in itself, just a link to another page... You should provide the substance of the link here (to prevent link rot) or post this as a comment.

Comment: @Sam : Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 4):

`schedule()` can be called in various ways, depending on if you want the task to execute once, or periodically.

To execute the task only once:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}, 3000);
```

To execute the task every second after 3 s.

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}, 3000, 1000);
```

More example usages can be found in the method headers

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date when) {
    // ...
}

public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) {
    // ...
}

public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) {
    // ...
}

public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date when, long period) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly that you hit the exception and get out of the Timer run method, thus interrupting the timer restart.